# Is there a way to access the underlying data store for an object with __slots__

Tags: python-3.x

In Perl 5 (bear with me) an object is made by strapping a bunch of magic to a reference to an hash (dictionary), an array, or pretty much anything else.

When introducing this concept to people, I try to liken this to the way it works in Python: objects by default are just fancy dictionaries; I can demostrate this by pointing to `some_object.__dict__`; this is true unless I use `__slots__`, in which case my object becomes a glorified tuple...

...is what I tell people, and they seem to buy it, and it appears that [indeed Python internals will turn the list of attribute *names* to a tuple](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8c663fd60ecba9c82aa4c404dbfb1aae69fe8553/Objects/typeobject.c#L2674). What about the actual values, however? Does *that* sit in a tuple? or do I fundamentally misunderstand `__slots__`?

If the values of `__slots__` do live in a tuple, is there a way I can (even only academically, i.e. at the iPython prompt; it can be evil non-production-ready trickery) show this at the repl?

Comment: Please note I don't actually understand the code I linked to; I just noticed it says "tuple" and the tuple is built at type creation time :)

Comment: Yes, the *names* are indeed stored as a tuple. The implementation, though, creates descriptors for each of those names. They aren't stored in a structure that you can nicely present via IPython.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard I'll be happy to access the names then with `__slots__`, but I still would like to learn more about that structure

Comment: The names are available via `__slots__`. You can easily show those, the tricky part, I'd guess, is then needing to explain that Python creates descriptors for these and what those are.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard I definitely don't want to go in that level of detail :)